# Parse html table with php - check class name

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to parse a table with following structure:

[image]

I am using PHP for that:

```
$html=file_get_contents("https://www.somesite.com/index");
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody') as $table) {                
        $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
            unset($col_array);
            $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            foreach ($cols as $col) {
                    $col_array[]=$col->textContent;
            }
            $row_array[]=$col_array;        
        }
        print_r ($row_array);
    }
```

The issue is that I want to grab only 'tr' elements with class "crc-row closed".

I was trying to add an if clause:

```
if ($rows->getAttribute('class')=="crc-row closed")
```

but it returns me an error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in**

Can anybody please help me?

thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you want the first item out of $rows rather than the whole $rows list? you could try `if ($rows[0]->getAttribute('class')=="space8")` or `if (current($rows)->getAttribute('class')=="space8")` or within your loop `if ($row->getAttribute('class')=="crc-row closed")` for a single $row

Comment: Not working ... I get another error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: where exactly did you add the if clause?

Comment: Right after $rows decloration, before foreach($rows as $row)

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve problem:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody') as $table) {

    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

            unset($col_array);

            if($row->getAttribute('class')=='crc-row'){

                $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
                foreach ($cols as $col) {
                        $col_array[]=$col->textContent;
                }
                $row_array[]=$col_array;
            }       
        }
        print_r ($row_array);
}
```